# Openmodelica simulation of large model with OPC client connection crashes

Tags: simulation, modelica, opc, openmodelica, open62541

I am using OpenModelica 1.18.0~dev-259-g9ebba11 on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 64bit and have developed a fluid system model that throws errors when simulating with the flags -embeddedServer=opc-ua -rt=0.1. Even though startup of the embedded opc server, connection to the UA Expert client and initialization all succeed, as soon as I set the "run"-variable to true, the process crashes:

[image: Modelica model]

[image: UA Expert output]

[image: Modelica output]

Unfortunately, I cannot make sense of the error output. If I remove a couple of components from the model (while trying to keep it as similar as possible), simulation magically runs just fine.

[image: Modelica model that simulates just fine]

Any ideas why this could happen, or where I could look for more debugging information?

I am grateful for any help.